# Force Committing via Netbeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, gitlab, git-commit

I've recently run into an issue when trying to commit and push a group project.

When trying to commit and push my changes to my team's GitLab through NetBeans, I encountered the "REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD" error. I've managed to resolve the nonfastforward issue, but was curious if there was any way to force a commit through NetBeans?

The way I was able to fix my REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD issues were to merge and rebase my origin/master.

**Is there any way to push my commits with --force through NetBeans? Or is it only possible via terminal?**

Comment: A force push may remove commits made by others from the target branch.

Comment: Yea, I know that there are possibilities of removing what others did, which would be bad practice, but I was just curious if it's even possible to --force via NetBeans. *Edit: A word

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251761 looks like no

Comment: After some tries, I don't think it supports force push. There is no option for force push in the menus, and its default push refspec is always like `refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/foo` even if `remote.origin.push=+refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/foo` is specified in config.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks for your effort! :D

Comment: @max630 Aw, yea, I was looking through logs but must have overlooked this one. Thanks!